# How to check your result when using dplyr Joins?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a way to find out about "extra" rows when using Joins?

I'm working with two tables with name data with the following structure:

```
table1 (6211 observations)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  name       count
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 surname1       1
2 surname4       1
3 surname5       1



table2 (611 observations)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  name         dummy_var
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 surname1        1
2 surname2        1
3 surname3        1
```

In table 2 all 611, names share a common trait, so they have a dummy_var column where the value is 1.
Now I want to join this table to the much larger data frame with 6211 people, but only where the names match.

I would then get:

```
  name       count  dummy_var
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 surname1       1    1
2 surname4       1    NA
3 surname5       1    NA
```

Which is what I want (or I would prefer to get 0 instead of NA's -- but that's not part of the question here).

Now this is the code I actually use:

```
table_join <- table1 %>% 
  left_join(table2, "name")
```

It seems to kinda work, however in table_join we have 6233 obs instead of the expected 6211!

**The question:**
**Now what I'd want to know what the best way / practice is for examining what has gone wrong.**

Can I get a sample of which observations are a part of those extra 22 observations in my new table somehow? It seems like It would be useful in these kinda situations.

SOLUTION:

So I think I understand now the problem.
Williams tip was useful. Table2 had a bunch of duplicates -- after they were removed, the problem disappeared.
This is how you remove duplicates:

```
table2 <- table2 %>% distinct(name)
```

I don't think any of the answers at moment are able to extract the "extra" line. Maybe you can't since R is just doing what I tell it to do? I guess the best way is to develop som intuition to what *can* go wrong and work with that.
Thanks for the replies!

Comment: You could try `setdiff(table_join$name, table1$name)` or you could tally how many times each name appears in both those tables, and see which differ. One typical explanation of your case is when you are joining none-unique data. For this you can run `duplicated(table2)` to see if you have duplicate rows which can cause double joins.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is a scenario for `anti_join`. It returns all rows from x where there are not matching values in y, keeping just columns from x. (and you can extend it vice versa).

```
table_join <- table1 %>% 
  anti_join(table2, "name")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name     count
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 surname4     1
2 surname5     1
```

data:

```
table1 <- structure(list(name = c("surname1", "surname4", "surname5"), 
    count = c(1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

table2 <- structure(list(name = c("surname1", "surname2", "surname3"), 
    dumm_var = c(1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I think OP doesn't want anti_join.  Tomas simply wants the reason why left_join is resulting in more rows than in leftdata!!

Answer (score 2):

**One possibility** see if there are more than one `dummy_var` allocated to one common `surname` in `table2`.  Check if

```
table2 %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(n() > 1)
```

results in any row.  IMHO there should be at least 22 such `names`.  See this example

```
table1 <- read.table(text = "name var
                 sname1 1
                 sname4 1
                 sname5 1", header = T)

table2 <- read.table(text = "name dvar
                 sname1 1
                 sname2 1
                 sname3 1
                 sname1 2", header = T)
table2

table1 %>% left_join(table2)
Joining, by = "name"
    name var dvar
1 sname1   1    1
2 sname1   1    2
3 sname4   1   NA
4 sname5   1   NA
```

Now see

```
table2 %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(n() >1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   name [1]
  name    dvar
  <chr>  <int>
1 sname1     1
2 sname1     2
```